# User is required error message

Tags: python, django

`print profile_form.errors`

Shows:

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Code:

```
def update(request):
    user    = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form    = RegistrationForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)

---

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address   = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=250, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2}))

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

---

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    country             = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=1)
    city                = models.ForeignKey(City, default=1)
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

How can I bypass that since the profile is already assigned to the user.

Comment: "What can I do about that? Please help." is not an answerable question. You need to edit and make it much more clear (and specific) what it is you're asking.

Comment: Your code says `user = get_object_or_404()`. Where do you check to see if you got `user` or `404`? Are you sure you got a valid `user`? You use it as if it succeeded, but I don't see anywhere there's a check to see if that's the case.

Comment: @KenWhite print user & print profile.user_id show the correct username being edited along with his profile ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form probably doesn't render a user field and the `ModelForm` is expecting one.

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address   = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=250, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2}))

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user', )  # <-- exclude user from your form
```